# How to remove / delete a CocoaPod?

Tags: cocoapods, podspec

I have a CocoaPods published on cocoaPods.org say 'ABC'. I want to remove it and delete it, in a way that anyone else can use the same name 'ABC' when publishing a new pod.What are the steps in doing so? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command to delete pod.

```
pod trunk delete
```

Reference: https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_trunk_delete

More Command: https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#group_trunk

Comment: Delete the pod on whose computer?

Comment: @ElTomato Owner computer. Who published the pod.

Comment: I think he or she wants to disable his or her published pod in use on any app.

Comment: According to the question, it seems like he/she wants to remove pod permanently. But if they want for their only purpose then he/she can use private pod I think. https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html

Comment: Yes, I want my pod to be completely removed, so no one can use it in the future and the name of the pod would be available to any other person.

Comment: @RajaKishan, will `pod trunk delete` would completely remove the pod and would it allow any other person to use that pod name when they are publishing their pod? Because `This name is already taken` error is haunting one.

Comment: honestly. I never used this command but as per the doc it will delete and allow someone else. also, you can change ownership as well. if you check in the terminal I think it will print something like ask owner etc. I don't remember what exactly line is.