# How to delete podspec completly from cocoapods repository

Tags: cocoapods

I've got an open-source library on Github (X) that relies on another library (Y). Unfortunately, Y got deleted and is no longer accessible. I've updated my podspec file and removed the dependency on Y, but when someone tries to install my library, they're getting an error saying, "Unable to find a specification for Y depended upon by X."

Do you have any ideas on how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove / delete a CocoaPod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68078262/how-to-remove-delete-a-cocoapod)

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Yes I did use that but it didn't work.
[!] No pod found with the specified name.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is different from your question: Whether you have access to Y or not, you need to publish the X podspec without the dependency on Y to CocoaPods trunk. Then the consumers need to do a `pod update` to get the new version of X.

Comment: I did that and it worked.